# Automatic adjust font size in Text() of SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Is there any way to automatically adjust the font size according to the length of the text to be displayed? For example, by setting the frame size? Can it reduce the font size automatically so that the width for displaying the font is still the same?

```
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { g in
                ZStack {
                    
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true, content: {
                    VStack {
                        ZStack {
                            VStack {
                                Image("cat")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(width:g.size.width, height:g.size.height/4*3)
                                    .clipped(antialiased:true)
                                    .shadow(radius:25, x:0, y:0)
                                
                                VStack (){
                                    HStack {
                                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                            HStack {
                                                Text("XXXX").font(.title)
                                               
                                                        .font(.system(size:35)).foregroundColor(.black).shadow(radius: 5)
                                                })
                                                Spacer()
                                                

                                            }
                                            HStack {
                                                Text("xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx ").font(.title2) // very long text here
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                .padding()
                                .frame(width:g.size.width, height:g.size.height/4*1, alignment: .top)
                            }
                        }.frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height, alignment: .top)
                        

            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

As you see in my code, there is a very long text there. The text can be displayed perfectly on most devices except iPod Touch where it will be displayed as "xxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxx  xxxx ... ", "..." at the end because it is too long to be displayed. Is there any way that it automatically, either jumps to the next line, or shrinks the fonts so that there will not be "..." at the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [minimumScaleFactor(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/minimumscalefactor(_:))

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Test string")
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.1) // <-- Here
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have included my code and clarify my question again.

Comment: @user6539552 Yes use this .minimumScaleFactor(0.1) after font. It will automatic make it two line and change the font size. if you give height then it will automatic adjust as per frame. I checked you code and it fixed by this.

Comment: May I know why we choose the factor to be 0.1?

Comment: It's a minimum scale which is eventually down the size of the font. You can set it as per your requirement. And i choose for very less frame size for the example.

Comment: Can I force it to become multi-line instead of shrinking the text?